# General VI plugin question, is it allowed?

Tags: discussion, question-quality

I'm a big fan of VIm, but every day I'm learning new possibilities. I am aware of the fact that plugins in VIm can be powerful, but I don't know a lot of them.

I'd like to start a question to let people share some of their favorite plugins. Is this question allowed?

Should it be a community wiki?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"What's your favorite X?" questions don't work well on Stack Exchange, even with community wiki. In order to be really useful, they need constant maintenance, and somewhat ironically, community wiki removes individual ownership, so no one is has incentive to do it.

So, my strong preference is not.

Comment: You have a good point here. Suppose I'm searching for a plugin doing something particular, this would be more appropiate?

Comment: IMO, those are really borderline too, search engines are built for that type of question. But, if you have searched, found a few plugins that sort of do what you want, but can't find the exact feature (or can't get it to work), then posting a detailed question showing your research effort & describing exactly what you're missing/what's not working for you should be ok. (IMO of course.)